# in org-mode, a function to delete all properties drawers?

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

I use Pandoc to convert from HTML and Markdown to org-mode. The conversion leaves lots of extraneous org-mode PROPERTIES drawers. How can I direct org-mode to delete all PROPERTIES drawers?

ADDITION: I'm using this shell script to run the conversion.

```
function pandoc2org () {
    basename=${1%%.*}                       # remove old file extension
    pandoc -s -S "$1" -o $basename.org      # name file as oldfile.org 
}
```

Comment: Why not a shell script to remove all lines starting with : ? You can pipe the output of pandoc directly into it. Or are there other drawers after the conversion too?

Comment: @dangom How would I do that?

Comment: Tried `pandoc -t org file.md | sed '/^:/ d'` to do that right now. Problem is the indentation (pandoc adding whitespaces). I'll get it working and post as an answer in a min

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using a shell script to accomplish what you want, you can try:

```
pandoc -t org file.md | sed -E "/^[[:space:]]+:/ d" > file.org
```

This will remove all lines starting with one (or more) spaces followed by a semicolon.

I believe you can fit it into your script by doing the following:

```
function pandoc2org () {
    basename=${1%%.*}                      
    pandoc -s -S "$1" -t org | sed -E "/^[[:space:]]+:/ d" > $basename.org
}
```

You can find an explanation of the function [here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=pandoc%20-s%20-S%20%22%241%22%20-t%20org%20%7C%20sed%20-E%20%22%2F%5E%5B%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D%5D%2B%3A%2F%20d%22%20%3E%20%24basename.org).

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks! How would I add this to my existing script?

Comment: @incandescentman just added an edit

Comment: Do you also know how to get the sed command to replace non-breaking spaces (`codepoint 160, #o240, #xa0`) with regular spaces? I tried adding `sed 's/\xA0/ /g'` but it didn't work.

Comment: Here's the script. The `;` format is correct but it's not finding the non-breaking space. https://gist.github.com/2aa13fbda1c12c7253bbedd6e6333a7a

Comment: Maybe have a look [at this superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/517847/use-sed-to-replace-nbsp-160-hex-00a0-octal-240-non-breaking-space)?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) you'll see that the -S option you are using in your script forces the insertion of non-breaking spaces. If there is no particular reason for you to use it, remove it.

Comment: Wow you're right. `-S` is definitely the wrong option for converting to org-mode, which already handles all that typographic stuff when exporting.

Comment: Update: The above works, but there is now a simpler method using LUA filters: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54400/export-a-docx-file-to-org-using-pandoc-but-without-the-property-drawers

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^\s*(:PROPERTIES:(.|\n)*?:END:)|(<<.*?>>)\s*$//gm'
```

to remove the extra stuff.

Also see [this question](https://groups.google.com/u/1/g/pandoc-discuss/c/j6aAPgRsg_A).