# Export a docx file to org using pandoc but without the property drawers

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

If I export a docx file to org using Pandoc as follows

```
pandoc -s test.docx -o test.org
```

I get a nice org file with markup. However, I also get unwanted properties with each heading in the file, generated from the headings. For example:

```
* Heading One
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: heading-one
  :END:
```

I don't want all these heading properties. Can I export without these drawers?

I found a similar article but this did not help me:

[in org-mode, a function to delete all properties drawers?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/in-org-mode-a-function-to-delete-all-properties-drawers/31907)

Otherwise, I would like to be able to strip the exported org file of all of its property drawers. Is this possible?

Comment: You could try exporting the resulting org file to a different org file, using the exporter that's built in to org mode in emacs,  by using `C-c C-e O o`. This will  produce a `test.org.org` file which has no drawers in it. Untested.

Comment: I tested this and it worked well with only one difference with the file created with tarleb's method: the org.org file has no space between header and text, whereas with tarleb's method the spaces are preserved.

Comment: I suspect that depending on the complexity of the document, there might be more differences as well. Glad you found a method that works for you! And the answer is informative: maybe it's time to learn something more about pandoc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The drawers are added only if a header has additional attributes. One can use a simple [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to remove all attributes from headers in pandoc's internal document format:

```lua
function Header (header)
  return pandoc.Header(header.level, header.content, pandoc.Attr())
end
```

Write the above to a file named `remove-header-attr.lua` and call pandoc with the additional parameter `--lua-filter=remove-header-attr.lua`.

Comment: I tested this and it worked flawlessly. Easy to implement.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is best solved on the level of pandoc conversion, with a pandoc filter.

Create a file, say `noattrs-filter.hs` containing:

```hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter noAttrs

noAttrs :: Block -> Block
noAttrs (Header n _ i) = Header n nullAttr i
noAttrs (Div _ b) = Div nullAttr b
noAttrs b = b
```

Compile the file with ghc:

```bash
ghc noattrs-filter.hs
```

and run your conversion with:

```bash
pandoc -s --filter ./noattrs-filter test.docx -o test.org
```

In order to compile the pandoc filter, you need to have the relevant libraries. For instance, on Ubuntu, you'd need the `libghc-pandoc-types-dev` package (`sudo apt-get install libghc-pandoc-types-dev`). More generally, you could also try installing via `cabal` (`cabal install pandoc`).

#### To understand the haskell filter

The relevant hackage documentation is [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.20/docs/Text-Pandoc-JSON.html) and [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.20/docs/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html#t:Block).

Adding comments to the code (starting with `--` and hopefully useful for somebody not used to haskell):

```hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter noAttrs

-- Type signature (convert a block into a slightly modified block)
noAttrs :: Block -> Block
-- Header constructors have the form:
--  Header Int Attr [Inline]
-- _ means we ignore the attribute (Attr), since we're discarding it, anyway
-- nullAttr is, as the name suggests, an attribute containing no info
noAttrs (Header n _ i) = Header n nullAttr i
-- Div constructors have the form:
--  Div Attr [Block]
noAttrs (Div _ b) = Div nullAttr b
-- for completeness could also deal with 'CodeBlock's, which can also
-- have an attribute — left as an exercise for the reader.
-- 
-- we need a fallthrough
noAttrs b = b
```

(This is based on my own answer to a relatively similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24676/html-to-orgmode-via-pandoc-get-rid-of-all-begin-html-blocks/37199#37199).)

Comment: Using a Lua filter, as answered by tarleb, rather than a compiled one, is probably the more portable solution (I simply prefer haskell to lua...).

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to test this solution on Windows as I failed to produce an install of pandoc with the required libraries. I would appreciate feedback from others on Linux who have tried it.